# Include a Netbeans Maven project in a Netbeans Ant project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, ant, include

I have a Netbeans Ant project that uses a Jar file generated from a Netbeans Maven project. I would like to "include" the Maven project directly in the Ant project to be able to proper debug both projects. The Maven project was converted from an Ant project and before the conversion this include was possible. I have control over both projects, but converting the Ant project to a Maven project is not really an option at this point. What is the best approach to make an Ant based project and a Maven based project "work" together i Netbeans?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work if your ant project includes the maven local repository jar as dependency. Maven support does automatic binary->open project source conversion for local repo artifacts.